# Monitoring the launch of process in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm to make a script whose purpose is to kill a process. If this process is launched it terminates it instantly and if this process isn't launched it performs an infinite loop until it detects the presence of the specified process.(The name of the process is typed by the user). An instruction code in the loop will delay this loop for 10 seconds at each iteration so as not to outrageously consume the system's resources. The shell periodically checks the presence or absence of the launch process.
The script should end when:
-it tracks the launched process
-or when the user has quit the application(process)
So far so good I when my script detects the launch process , it terminates the process and the quits but it doesn't quit when the user quits the application instead it continues to loop. Actually I don't really now how to detect if the user has quit the application. Any ideas please? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter the name of the process to monitor "
read nom

while :
do
    compteur=` ps -u $USER | grep $nom | cut -d " " -f2 `

    if [ $compteur >0 ]
    then
        kill $compteur 
        echo " Process terminated "
        exit 1
    else
        echo " Searching $nom... "

    fi
    sleep 10;
done
```

Comment: You should use `pgrep` to simplify your script a bit.

Comment: By "when the user has quit the application(process) " you mean that process started and completed in a 10 second window your script is sleeping?

Comment: Within the 10 seconds in which my script is sleeping, if the user opens, uses (or not) and closes the application within the 10 seconds, the program should quit. I know it might not sound too practical. I can increase it to a minute or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
if [ $compteur >0 ]
```

in the Bourne shell (`#!/bin/sh`) it needs to be:

```
if [ $compteur -gt 0 ]
```

or in Bash (`#!/bin/bash`) it can be the previous or:

```
if [[ $compteur -gt 0 ]]
```

or

```
if (( compteur > 0 ))
```

That is, if you're doing a numeric comparison. Your `ps` command is unreliable since leading spaces in the PID will throw it off and you will get false positives for at least a couple of reasons. Also, at least on my system, `ps -u username` outputs the PID in the first column.

You should use `pgrep` and `pkill`.

To answer your primary question, change your `while :` (forever) to:

```
while pkill -0 $PID
```

So your script would look something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter the name of the process to monitor "
read nom

compteur=`pgrep -U $USER "$nom"`

while pkill -0 $compteur 2>/dev/null
do
    sleep 10
    kill $compteur && echo " Process terminated "
done
```

However, another problem is what to do if there is more than one such process.

Please see [Process Management](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Dennis for the tips and correction. Actually my teacher doesn't want us to use pgrep and pkill. She wants us to make use of the pipes, the seds, the greps and whatnot. And I already tried using {if [ $compteur -gt 0 ]} and {if test $compteur -gt 0} but it gives me this error:                                            -gt: unexpected operator. That's why i changed it to if [ compteur>0 ] and it works for some reason i guess

Comment: @mkab: `[ compteur>0 ]` creates a file named "0" and usually returns `true`. Try `a=-1; if [ $a>0 ]; then echo 'Wait! Negative one shouldn't be greater than zero!'; fi; ls -l 0`

Comment: Yeah it did created a file named "0" and executed the function in the if loop when it's not suppose to do that because -1 is never greater than 0. So that mean the if condition would always be true. I get it now. One other thing: How can I know if the variable in a script is a string or a number so as to use the appropriate test in the if loop? I kinda mix java with shell scripting. For example a variable in java can contain a string of numbers `String str = "4453"`. You see what I mean?

Comment: @mkab: In Unix shells, variables are strings by default regardless of their contents. You can `declare -i varname` to set its type to integer. It's always safe to do a string comparison regardless of whether the value is a string or a number. If you want to validate that a variable contains a number and you haven't used `declare -i` there are various ways to do it. One might be to do `if [[ $((var)) == $var ]] && ((var > 0)); then echo "var is greater than zero"; fi` it will skip the second test if the first one fails.

Answer (score 0):

I recently learned that it's generally not advised to kill processes by name but by process id (pid), which assumes you to manage parent/children pids.

In your case, you should have a careful look at [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), checking these points below, all described in the link I just gave :

- getting the launched process id
- checking if that process is still running
- waiting for the pid graceful end (eg generally exit status code 0)
- killing a running process